# Disable tracking for specific link in Mailchimp

Tags: mailchimp, ios-universal-links

I'd like to disable tracking for a specific link in a campaign.

The reason I need to do this is Mailchimp/Mandrill's tracking creates a scenario where Universal Links do not work.

Example:

[image]

I'd like (1) to be a regular link, with no Mailchimp tracking
I'd like (2) to track as normal.

In Mandrill I achieve this by adding `mc:disable-tracking` to the HTML of my template

Is it possible to do this within Mailchimp?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From my experience with MailChimp, you can't turn off click tracking on a link-by-link basis. It's all or nothing for a given campaign. MailChimp has a [support document](http://kb.mailchimp.com/reports/enable-and-view-click-tracking) on how to do this, but the gist of it is a simple checkbox when configuring the campaign options:

[image]

Incidentally lack of click tracking in emails is currently a major drawback of Universal Links. If you're using one of the major email systems (Responsys, ExactTarget, SendGrid, or SailThru) [Branch.io](https://branch.io) *[full disclosure: I'm on the Branch team]* offers an integration to fix this, but unfortunately the MailChimp version is taking somewhat longer to get live (feel free to let them know you want such a thing!)

Comment: Thanks Alex! I was talking to Kevin last week and put my vote in for it

Comment: 2024 and Mailchimp still has this issue